# update Knockout observablearray item property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel, signalr

I'm using ko.utils.arrayFirst to get a matching item from my view model, then trying to update one of it's properties, but I'm getting a "is not a function" error.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm getting the error when I call match.NewMessage("").  Shouldn't match be an instance of an item in my observable array from my view model?  SendMessage is a function defined on my view model, hence the "self" references, and InstantMessages is defined as a ko.observableArray.

```
self.SendMessage = function (im) {
    var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.InstantMessages(), function (item) {
        return im.InstantMessageId === item.InstantMessageId;
    });

    if (match) {
        var newMessage = new Chat.Message();
        newMessage.FromUser = self.User;
        newMessage.Text = match.NewMessage;
        newMessage.InstantMessageId = match.InstantMessageId;

        match.NewMessage("");

        self.ChatHub.server.sendMessage(newMessage).fail(function (e) { alert(e); });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you've defined InstantMessages as a ko.observableArray(), it doesn't mean that all of the properties in the objects contained in the array are observable as well.

The NewMessage property needs to be initialised as a ko.observable()

```
var im;
im.NewMessage = ko.observable();
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer isn't exactly what I needed as I do have the properties marked as ko.observable(), but you pointed me in the right direction. When adding items to the collection, I was adding an object (returned from the server) that has the same properties as the object I want to be adding. I just need to instantiate an instance of that object type and set property values accordingly, then add that object to the collection instead of the one returned from the server.